# Why is my first row of DIVs missing a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of `inline-block` DIVs with some CSS style attributes::

```css
.main {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item-cont {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
}

.item {
    width:100%;
    max-width:250px;
    min-width:200px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.item-cap {
    background:white;
    padding:5px 10px;
    color:dimgray;
    font-weight:normal;
    float:left;
}

.item-act {
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    background:goldenrod;
    color:white;
    padding:5px 10px;
}

.item-act-rep {
    font-weight:normal;
    background:white;
    color:gray;
}

.item-act-save {
    margin-right:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
            <div class="item-cont">
                <img class="item" src="1.gif"><br>
                <a class="item-cap" href="#">#catch</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-save" href="#">Save</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-like" href="#">Like</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-rep" href="#">Report</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cont">
                <img class="item" src="1.gif"><br>
                <a class="item-cap" href="#">#catch</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-save" href="#">Save</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-like" href="#">Like</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-rep" href="#">Report</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cont">
                <img class="item" src="1.gif"><br>
                <a class="item-cap" href="#">#catch</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-save" href="#">Save</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-like" href="#">Like</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-rep" href="#">Report</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cont">
                <img class="item" src="1.gif"><br>
                <a class="item-cap" href="#">#catch</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-save" href="#">Save</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-like" href="#">Like</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-rep" href="#">Report</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cont">
                <img class="item" src="1.gif"><br>
                <a class="item-cap" href="#">#catch</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-save" href="#">Save</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-like" href="#">Like</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-rep" href="#">Report</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cont">
                <img class="item" src="1.gif"><br>
                <a class="item-cap" href="#">#catch</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-save" href="#">Save</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-like" href="#">Like</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-rep" href="#">Report</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cont">
                <img class="item" src="1.gif"><br>
                <a class="item-cap" href="#">#catch</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-save" href="#">Save</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-like" href="#">Like</a>
                <a class="item-act item-act-rep" href="#">Report</a>
            </div>
            **and so on ***
        </div>
```

And here's what my browser shows:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLWtN.png)

Seems like a DIV is missing on the first row. I tried to edit my CSS code by changing the size of the different elements (containers, images, body, etc.) but couldn't find how to make it work... How can I fix it?

Comment: @Quentin the edit is wrong. The line "<div class="main">" doesn't repeat twice in my code. It's only there once.

Comment: Pretty hard to do this without an inspector, can you create a working version of your issue for us to look at?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa An solution that works was given by someone and was deleted for some reason (typical StackOverflow) :

.main {
 width:100%;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item-cont {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:20px;
}

Comment: @MaashaTheytaz it was a blind solution that have a luck to work .... I think it's good to first understand the issue and then try to fix or are you simply intresting on a blind fix?

Comment: It was a solution of a professional developer. If you call it a blind solution -- you are mistaken.

Comment: actually your code reproduce nothing, try to edit it to have the same output as the image

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes we could have if it wasn't deleted.

Comment: @MaashaTheytaz it's here

Comment: @Arfeo can the professional developer also explain the issue then? .. a code dump whithout explanation (especially the common "use flexbox it's wonderful") is a blind solution for me

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh well... okay. as someone said -- typical SO.

Comment: @Arfeo yes of course, what else this could be besides *typical SO* :) .. a question without issue and an answer that fixes a virtual issue.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, excuse me, I have no time for typical SO blah-blah. As you could notice, my minused solution was accepted by the owner, that only means everything was done right.

Comment: @Arfeo ok it's accepted congratulations but can you explain me the issue? because *me* I am intrested to know why it wasn't working and how your code fix it. I think this is the main purpose of this site, to understand issues and avoid them.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, did you try to look at the code? What happens if you run the code above in your browser. I almost completely sure it works fine. But the owner had the trouble. It means that smth else on the page has broken the markup. I gave an example of markup that will work, just added 3 lines. It worked. Fast and fine solution. Why are you so weird??... Did you notice that the owner wrote: "How can I fix it?" That is (one of many variants of) how it can be fixed. I have answered the owner's question.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

As the provided code works well, I guess smth else on the page breaks your markup. You can try to "override" this side-effect switching `.main` display property like this for example:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item-cont {
  min-width: 25%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
}

...
```

But you'd better inspect your CSS code for the initial problem.